# Php soap client + getting null response

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

**I am trying to call a wcf ws from php client**

WSDL     https://ws-web.test.nhn.no/v1/AR?wsdl

```
$url = 'https://ws-web.test.nhn.no/v1/AR?wsdl';
$params = array('login' => '*****',
    'password' => '######',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => TRUE);

$client = new SoapClient($url, $params);
var_dump($client->__soapCall("Ping"));
```

With the above code I am always getting a `null` response and I am not able to call other functions from `wsdl`

If I try this with another syntax sometimes I get an `action mismatch error` and I am also getting a `null` response in Soap UI.

Comment: I think the params are invalid. Can you check if you get a null response if you set no login and password?

Comment: @PeterDarmis m getting successful response for client variable so i think till there everything goes well :(

can anybody just elaborate how to predict variable names and functions from wsdl

Comment: i think i have to change authentication method to basic from WS-Security any body having any idea how to do it in php soap ?

Comment: You should have a look at this http://php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapclient.php#114976

Answer (score 0):

Based on the WSDL, the Ping function has an input message.

```
<wsdl:operation name="Ping">
    <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://register.nhn.no/CommunicationParty/ICommunicationPartyService/Ping" message="tns:ICommunicationPartyService_Ping_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://register.nhn.no/CommunicationParty/ICommunicationPartyService/PingResponse" message="tns:ICommunicationPartyService_Ping_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Input message consists of parameters defined here ...

```
<wsdl:message name="ICommunicationPartyService_Ping_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Ping"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

And finally the Ping object doesn't look like it has any properties. Weird.

```
<xs:element name="Ping">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So give this a try.

```
$pingObj = new stdClass();
$client->__soapCall("Ping", [$pingObj]);
```